Celery class based tasks found in the worker, but gets NotRegistered when consumed
I am configuring Celery like that
from celery import Celery

from settings.config import settings

celery_app = Celery(
    broker=settings.RABBITMQ_URL,
    backend="rpc://",
)

celery_app.config_from_object(settings.CELERY_SETTINGS_MODULE)
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(["app.tasks"], force=True)

In another file, I have:
class AsyncTask(celery.Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        coro = self._run(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            result = self._thread_isolated_worker(coro)
            return result
        except (DeprecatedTimeoutError, TimeoutError):
            raise TimeoutError
    @abstractmethod
    async def task(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something




async_task = celery_app.register_task(AsyncTask())

When I run the worker, I see the task registered, but when I run
this simple script
from app.tasks import async_task
async_task.delay().get()

I get
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'async_task'

Celery version: celery==5.3.6
If I run a task, that is registered with the usual @shared_task decorator it works fine.
I think it's something related to the registrations, but it looks correct to me.

When you run Celery worker in the console, does it report that task as registered?

@DejanLekic It does. And also the task is listed under celery_app.tasks.keys()

I've never used class-based tasks to be honest so I could be wrong here...
Anyway, I think the issue here is how you call your task.
The following should work if I understand it well:
from app.tasks import AsyncTask


async_task = AsyncTask()
async_task.delay().get()


it should, but it doesn't, and the error is the same, unfortunately

Could it be that it connects to wrong broker?

I had the same thought, but it is not
